# Retrieve raw SQL executed by active_record methods not responding to to_sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to find a way to retrieve the raw SQL executed by active-record methods that are directly executing the query and don't respond to `to_sql`.
For instance `find, find_by, take, pluck` cant be chained with the `to_sql` method.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I'm not sure it will help you or not, but you could log the queries with https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#sql-active-record

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is because with find and find_by you get a single object or an array of objects if you pass in multiple ids and not an ActiveRecord::Relation.
With a single id this is what find does under the hood:

```rb
# the record method processes the query and returns an array of Person instances
# because the limit(1) there will only be 1 instance
# with first you get the first item of the array
# there is no information about the query only a Person instance
Person.where(Person.primary_key => 1).limit(1).records.first
```

With take you will get an array of objects instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation.

```rb
# Take does this under the hood
# if limit is set
limit(limit).to_a
# if limit is not set
limit(1).to_a
```

With pluck you get an array of the selected fields. If you like to get raw sql you should use where instead of find and find_all, limit instead of take and select instead of pluck.

```rb
   # instead of Person.find(1)
   Person.where(id: 1).limit(1).to_sql
   # Or instead of Person.find([1, 2, 3])
   Person.where(id: [1, 2, 3]).to_sql
   # instead of Person.find_by(name: 'John Doe')
   Person.where(name: 'John Doe').limit(1).to_sql
   # instead of Person.where(salutation: 'Mr.').take(10)
   Person.where(salutation: 'Mr.').limit(10).to_sql
   # instead of Person.where(salutation: 'Mr.').limit(10).pluck(:name)
   Person.select(:name).where(salutation: 'Mr.').limit(10).to_sql
```

Comment: Not sure what the down vote was for as you have provided viable alternatives for each requested method (excepting `find` is technically `where(id: 1).limit(1)`) but otherwise I agree with this `find_by` -> `where`, `pluck` -> `select`, `take` -> `limit` from a query perspective